# jdbc code to update informations in a mysql table

Tags: java, jdbc

i have a code in java-eclipse to update the informations in a table with mysql but the values in selected row of the table didnt update after running this function.for example i want to replace value "b" inested of "a" in column "username" please help me :(

a is first value
b is value that i want to replace with a
username is name of the one column
my code:

```
   public void Change("username","a","b") throws SQLException{
        prs=connect.prepareStatement( "UPDATE user0 SET " +s1+ "='" +s3+ "' WHERE '" +s1+ "'='" + s2+"'");
        prs.execute();      
    }// end of function change
```

Comment: I think if you use `try...catch` and print the *error* with your question it will be much more easier to help you .

Comment: As I noticed you used `'` for `s1` which is a field and don't need it,try this : `UPDATE user0 SET " +s1+ "='" +s3+ "' WHERE " +s1+ "='" + s2+"'"`

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't even compile, your syntax is wrong:

```
public void Change(String username, String a, String b) throws SQLException{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having trouble with all that quotation. It's better to use what `PreparedStatement` has to offer, for example:

```
prs = connect.prepareStatement("UPDATE Users SET UserName = ? WHERE IDUser = ?");
prs.setString(1, "some String");
prs.setInt(2, 145);
prs.execute();
```

Probably with that you'll be able to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that is not an exact excerpt of your code. If it is, then you should change the prototype part to

```
void Change(String s3, String s1, String s2) throws SQLException
```

Now, the code itself is prone to SQL injection.

Seeing as you are using a PreparedStatement, you should first declare it:

```
PreparedStatement prs;
```

Afterwards, you should set the parameters according to their type. See how to use PreparedStatement here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html .

Last but not least, please try to format the code you enter in a question. Good luck! :)

Later edit: you should also use `executeUpdate()` instead of `execute()`. It will return an integer corresponding to the number of rows that were updated. You can then write that number in the console to see if your update went ok. Remember that `executeUpdate()` is for `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` only :)